# Unable to create multiple data files

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to create multiple file for the some purpose and store different set of data into them. but this code does't seems to work. Moreover there is another trouble. I am not able to enter teacher name in output window.please help me to correct this code.
here is the function that i am using to do all this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
struct teacher{
int id;
char name[50];
char subject[50];
char qualification[50];
char experience[50];
};
teacher teacher;
void addition(int a)
{
char ans='y';
    do
    {
    teacher.id=a;   

    fstream sfile;
    sfile.open("id.dat",ios::app|ios::out|ios::binary);

    cout<<"\n enter the teacher name"<<endl;
    gets(teacher.name);
    cout<<"enter subject taught by teacher"<<endl;
    gets(teacher.subject);

    cout<<"enter qualification "<<endl;
    gets(teacher.qualification);
    cout<<"enter experience"<<endl;
    gets(teacher.experience);
    sfile.write((char*)&teacher,sizeof(teacher));
    cout<<"continue... (y/n)";
    cin>>ans;
    sfile.close();

    }
    while(ans=='y');
}
int main(void)
{
int a,t_id;
cout<<"1:NEW TEACHER REGISTRATION AND TIME TABLE CREATION"<<endl;
cout<<"2:MODIFY EARLIER DATA"<<endl;
cin>>a;
char ans='y';
if (a==1)
{
    cout<<"enter the teacher id";
    cin>>t_id;
    addition(t_id);
}
//please neglect case 2.

}
```

Help me with code or please suggest any other better method to do this.
All i want to generate multiple number of files for every time i call this function.

Comment: Is this the complete program??

Comment: Yes, this is the structure and function that is use. Although I havnt mentioned the main.

Comment: Do you know what a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is?

Comment: I didn't knew about that.

Comment: But if want to test this code, all you have to do is to make a main function and call this function again and again.

Comment: Send me a pm if you want to pay me to test your code and tell you how to make it do what you want it to do.

Comment: I am doing this for learning purpose only! Thanks for your interest.

Comment: So maybe you can learn to ask good questions?

Comment: Thanks.I will read that document and try to ask good questions next time.

Comment: Why don't you improve this question? You know there is an "edit" button there below it, right?

Comment: Apologies. Give me a little time.

Comment: it seems to me that from my code i am not able to create different files but only  a single file. can anyone tell me how can i generate a different file for   a every single teacher?

Comment: How do you expect to get different files if you name them all the same?

Comment: You see, that's why I made a function that takes an integer as an argument to call and then assigned it to t_id. But this isn't working. Can you tell me how can I create different files ? Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: No, you are not doing this. You assign the value of `a` to `teacher.id` (unnecessary), then you name the file with the string constant `"t_id.dat"`.

Answer (score 0):

ios::ate is an mode which is used to read an file.

change the code bellow:

```
sfile.open("t_id.dat",ios::ate); // should change the open mode, then. as follows
sfile.open("t_id.dat",ios::app|ios::out|ios::binary)
```

it will works.

Comment: Certainly , I am able to create a file with a name t_id. But I wanted to create a different file with different name for every time this function is called. Do you know any method for this?

Answer (score 0):

The cheap way be to convert the integer to a string and append it to the file name, for example:

```
...
string filename("foo");
filename += std::to_string(a);
filename += ".dat";
...
```

There is no such magic that will guess what you want by looking at the code you wrote.